# number of dfa's that can be designed

Tags: finite-automata, automata, computation-theory, dfa, automata-theory

Can we calculate the total number (i.e maximum no.) of dfa's that can be designed when the following constraints are put: |Q|=2{No. of states is 2},|Ɛ|=2{No. of alphabets} and |F|=1{No. of Final States} ?

Comment: Cross-posted on CS.SE: http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/56153/755.  
Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068). Each community should have an honest shot at answering without anybody's time being wasted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I am guessing that by "No. of alphabets," you are actually referring to the number of symbols in THE alphabet.  I haven't heard of a finite automaton with multiple alphabets.

Next, the definition of a finite automaton that I have is:
A finite automaton M is a quintuple M = (S,I,δ,s0,F) where:
S is a finite set (of states)
I is a finite alphabet (of input symbols) 
δ: S × I → S (next state function)
s0 ∈ S (the starting state)
F ⊆ S (the accepting states).

So your definition maps to mine in that Q -> S    Ɛ -> I  and F -> F

Now, which state is the starting state leads to different automata, so this is an important factor and cannot be left out. If you have 2 states, then choosing a different final state out of the two leads to two different automata. Now assuming that there must be a transition function for each symbol in the alphabet for each state, then examining just a single state to begin with, for each state, each of the two symbols (call them a and b) must have a transition function.  The value of the transition function for each symbol can be one of two possible states.  Therefore, for a single state, there are a possibility of 2 x 2 = 4 transition functions.  Since there are two states, there is another 4 possible transition functions for the second state.  Accounting for the possibility of different initial/final states, there are 8 x 2 x 2 = 32 possible DFAs that you may design.

Comment: Could you make a generalized result to calculate the no of dfa given all the parameters or the necessary values which would make it easy to compute the no of dfa directly by looking at the no of alphabets and states.Is that possible?